# How to set expectations for implicit parameters using ScalaMock?

Tags: scala

Using version 3.0.1, attempting to mock the following function:

```
(cycleCollapseMock.collapseCycles[RoomVertex, UnDiEdge] _) expects(dummyGraph) returns(graph) once()
```

The result is a class cast exception where MockFunction2 gets cast as MockFunction1. I assume this is because RoomVertex requires a classtag, which gets translated into an implicit parameter by the compiler. Is it possible to set expectations for this implicit as well?

**Update**: This works:

```
(cycleCollapseMock.collapseCycles[RoomVertex, UnDiEdge](_: Graph[RoomVertex, UnDiEdge])(_: ClassTag[RoomVertex])) expects(dummyGraph, classTag[RoomVertex]) returns(graph) once()
```